# Having trouble with jsonconverter.bas parsing json with vba excel

Tags: json, excel, vba, parsing

Im trying to run the following code but I am getting a type mismatch error:

```
Public Sub exceljson()
Dim http As Object, JSON As Object, i As Integer
Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
http.Open "GET", "https://wex.nz/api/3/ticker/btc_usd-ltc_usd", False
http.Send
Set JSON = ParseJson(http.responseText)
i = 2
For Each Item In JSON

Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value = Item("high")
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value = Item("low")
i = i + 1
Next
MsgBox ("complete")
End Sub
```

The example code below worked fine when I was using it:

```
Public Sub exceljson()
Dim http As Object, JSON As Object, i As Integer
Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
http.Open "GET", "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", False
http.Send
Set JSON = ParseJson(http.responseText)
i = 2
For Each Item In JSON
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = Item("id")
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value = Item("name")
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value = Item("username")
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4).Value = Item("email")
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 5).Value = Item("address")("city")
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 6).Value = Item("phone")
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 7).Value = Item("website")
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 8).Value = Item("company")("name")
i = i + 1
Next
MsgBox ("complete")
End Sub
```

I'm not sure what the difference between the two sites is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to examine the structure of the JSON more closely.

Because you chose to not specifically declare your `Item` variable, it gets implicitly declared as a `Variant` (which is OK in this instance).

In your first macro, the `Item` is a `String` so you need to reference that as a key.

In your second macro, the `Item` will be a `Dictionary` object, so you can reference it the way you did.

So in your 1st macro, you need something like:

```
For Each Item In JSON
    Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value = JSON(Item)("high")
    Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value = JSON(Item)("low")
    i = i + 1
Next
```

Comment: what if the items are nested like in this link:  https://wex.nz/api/3/depth/btc_usd-ltc_usd

Comment: @Brett You need to "descend" through them.  The api documentation should provide you the structure and types; or you can determine by using the Immediate and Watch windows.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with parsing with vba. I know with python to get a value it would be `['btc_usd']['asks'][0][0]` would the vba be something like:

Comment: `JSON(Item)("asks")(0)(0)`

Comment: @Brett `json(item)("asks")(1)(1)`